# Is there a category-theoretic generalisation of function application?

Tags: functions, category-theory

(I'll be using functional programming jargon, because my category theory is not too good).

Is the notion of function application, i.e. the application `f a` of a function `f :: a -> b` to a value `a :: a` to yield a value `b :: b`, peculiar to functions, or is there a more general category-theoretic concept to generalise it?

Comment: Function types correspond precisely to [exponential objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_object) in a cartesian category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions are morphisms in the category of sets. A morphism  $$e:S\rightarrow X$$ from any singleton S set to another set X (object in category Set), "picks out" an element of X. The composition of a morphism $$f:X\rightarrow Y$$ with the morphism e, $$f\circ e$$ "picks out" the value of f applied to the "value" of e.

Comment: Thanks. I think you've improved my understanding of category theory, but I'm still out of my depth here... I think my actual question is about the mapping of category-theoretic concepts to Haskell, which is out of scope of this site.

Answer (score 2):

(This should be rather a comment, but I will post it as an answer as it is too long)

Besides exponential objects as mention in the comments there is another way of 'evaluating' functions/morphisms:

In a general category we replace the elements (in the set-theoretic sense) with morphisms:

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category and $X$ an object in $\mathcal{C}$. We will call a morphism $T\to X$ a "generalized element of shape $T$" or (in algebraic geometry) "$T$-valued point of $X$". Now if you have a morphism $f:X\to Y$ and a generalized element $a$ of shape $T$ of $X$ we get an element $f(a)$ of the same shape of $Y$, i.e. $$f(a):=f\circ a$$
In the category of sets we know that two maps (with the same source and target) are equal iff they agree on elements (in the set-theoretic sense). Now this carries over to these generalized elements. Two morphisms $f,g:X\to Y$ are equal iff $f(a)=g(a)$ for all objects $T$ and generalized elements $a$ of shape $T$ of $X$.

As an example: In the category of sets we can identify the usual elements with these generalized elements of a certain shape $T$, in this case take $T$ to be your favorite set with one element. It is similar in the category of groups: here the usual elements of a group $G$ correspond exactly to the morphisms $\mathbb{Z}\to G$, that is to the generalized elements of shape $\mathbb{Z}$ of $G$.

Comment: It's much more common terminology to call a morphism $T\to X$ a generalized element of type $X$, not type $T$; similarly, you'd call it $X$-valued (since typical terminology has morphisms "valued" in their codomain).

Comment: Dear @MaliceVidrine, what I wrote was indeed not quite correct, I changed it from "element of type $T$" to "generalized element of shape $T$", however I am not sure why you want to call it it type $X$ or $X$-valued? It doesn't seem to make much sense to call a morphism $\operatorname{Spec}K\to X$ an "$X$-valued point of $X$". You can also find this notation of "generalized element of shape $T$" (not $X$) in books, like 'Basic Category Theory' by Tom Leinster or "Einführung in die Kategorientheorie" (German) by Martin Brandenburg. Maybe you can clarify this misunderstanding?

Comment: It is a peculiarity of algebraic geometry that morphisms $\operatorname{Spec} k \to X$ are called $k$-valued points of $X$. But if $X = \operatorname{Spec} A$ then such a morphism corresponds to a homomorphism $A \to k$, and here $k$ is the codomain as you would expect.

Comment: I wasn't advocating for you to keep the "$-$ valued point of $-$" language in any form, only pointing out that "$-$ valued" is typically codomain-centric. I have never read anything that used the phrase "$-$ valued point", so I would abandon it entirely. That said, Zhen Lin does provide a precedent for using your language that I was unaware of. It's definitely not common terminology, though.